# Help on question regarding diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My professor gave us a question and I would like some help in it.
The problem goes as follows:
Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear transformation represented by:
$T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1-x_2-x_3,x_1+3x_2+x_3,-3x_1+x_2-x_3)$

a) Find the standard matrix $A$ for T.

b) Show that $A$  is diagonalizable.

c) Compute $A^3$.

d) Find a basis $B$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the matrix $A$ relative to $B$ is diagonal.

Here is what I know:

a) $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 3 & 1 \\
-3 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$

b) $\det(\lambda I-A)=0$

where the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^3-3\lambda^2-4\lambda+12$. Therefore the eigenvalues are $2,-2,3$. Since there are 3 distinct eigenvalues for the matrix A which is in $\mathbb{R}^3$, A is diagonalizable. 
However, I proceeded to find the bases because I need them for part c). Here's where I'm stuck.
I found the basis for when $\lambda=2$ and got
$p_1=\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$ and 
$p_2=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$. However, the basis for $\lambda=2$ is 
$p_1=\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$.

Where did I go wrong?
Edit: I included further calculations
For $\lambda=2$,

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
-1 & -1 & -1\\
3 & -1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

This reduces to
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

So, $x_1+x_3=0, x_2=0, x_3=0$.
Then, $x_1=-t, x_2=s,x_3=t$

Hence,
$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}=$ $\begin{bmatrix}
-t\\
s\\
t
\end{bmatrix}$=$t\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}+$$s\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

So,
$p_1=\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$,$p_2=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the eigenvectors for the basis, you have to compute the basis for $\ker(2I - A), \ker(-2I - A), \ker(3I - A)$. For example, I'll set the first.

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc} -1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ -3 & 1 & -3 \end{array}\right] \left [\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ z \end{array}\right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right] $$

Can you go on?

Comment: Shouldn't $ker(2I-A)$ be \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 \\
3 & -1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}

Comment: Yes. However $\ker(2I - A) = \ker(A - 2I)$, so there is no harm done.

Comment: Okay. So then that's what I did and got that. There's a point where the matrix reduces to  \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} and then $x_1=-x_3, x_2=0$, and $x_3=0$

Comment: Great. So your $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix}$ is actually $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ 0 \\ -x_1 \end{bmatrix}$, which can be written as $x_1 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$. This does not conflict with the $p_1$ you found - they're multiples. Now, on to the next (:

Comment: How is  $\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
0 \\
-1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: It is not. I substituted the $x_2 = 0$ and the $x_3 = -x_1$, then factored $x_1$ out of the vector, pay close attention and you will see.

Comment: Is it because $x_1=-x_3$? Then $x_3=-x_1$? Even so, how do I get the actual basis?

Comment: You will have one basis eigenvector for each eigenvalue. All three of them form the basis on which the matrix is diagonal. We already found one.. Now you have to do the same for the other kernels.

Comment: If you need any more help, just ask. By the way, if the answer were helpful, you can always upvote it.

Comment: Okay, from inspection, what do you think I did incorrectly? Because I got the final column vector to be  \begin{bmatrix}
 -t\\
s \\
t \end{bmatrix}where $x_1=-x_3,x_2=s, and x_3=t$. So that's how I got my bases.

Comment: There is something off, indeed, you should have only one free variable, not two. Can you edit your question with all your calculations on this one, so I analyze better?

Comment: I added the calculations I did.

Comment: Well. Some considerations. Doesn't make sense to introduce variables like $s$ and $t$, since you can work with the relations between $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$. Other thing that's off is: the link correspondent to $x_3$ being made of zeroes does **not** imply that $x_3$ is zero himself. Lines with only zeroes can be thrown away. By the second line, $x_2 = 0$ indeed. And finally $x_1 = -x_3$. And like I said earlier, substituting, we get $$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ 0 \\ -x_1 \end{bmatrix} = x_1 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$$